# Remove shipping address option in PayPal Express Checkout

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I am using the JS [script](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/basic-integration/) recommended by PayPal. It's working well, however it is showing a **"Ship to"** address of the buyers.

I am trying to search the internet and found that `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payment-experience/web-profiles/` requested with `"no_shipping": 1,` can do the trick. But for that we need to make a curl request before the `payment.create`, so that we can pass it returned id in the function.

**Is this possible in JS?**

**Or is there a much better and simpler way to remove it using the following JS?**

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" data-version-4></script>
<script>

    paypal.Button.render({
        env: 'sandbox', // Optional: specify 'sandbox' or 'production'
        client: {
            sandbox:    '{{$data['SandboxId']}}',
            production: '{{$data['ProductionId']}}'
        },

        payment: function() {
            var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
            var env    = this.props.env;
            var client = this.props.client;

            return paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: {
                            total: amount,
                            currency: "USD",
                            details: {
                                subtotal: amount,
                                tax: "0.00",
                                shipping: "0.00"
                            }
                        },
                        description: "This is payment description.",
                        item_list: { 
                            items:[
                                {
                                    quantity:"1", 
                                    name:"Orders", 
                                    price:amount,  
                                    sku:"product12345", 
                                    currency:"USD"
                                }
                            ],
                        },

                    }],

            });
        },

        commit: false, // Optional: show a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
                console.log(data);
                 alert('confirmation here');
                // Optional: display a confirmation page here

            return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                alert('Success here');
                // Show a success page to the buyer
            });
        },
    }, '#paypal-button');
</script><div id="paypal-button" ></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

To expand on Bluepnume's answer, here is a complete example:

```
  payment: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.create({
            payment: {
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: { total: '1.00', currency: 'USD' }
                    }
                ]
            },

            experience: {
                input_fields: {
                    no_shipping: 1
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: Note: It seems that only the main PayPal sandbox account is authorized to specify "experience", and the subsidiary sandbox accounts are not.  (the PayPal account is specified in paypal.Button.render's client field)

I mention this because I was getting a 401 unauthorized error in the javascript console when I tried the above code passing in the experience parameters while using a non-primary sandbox client id.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an experience options like so:

```
paypal.rest.payment.create({
    // payment options here
}, {
    // experience options here
});
```

Comment: Hi Blueprnum! Is there any documentation for this? I tried adding NOSHIPPING as the experience option but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it needs to be done in ngx-paypal version 11

```
application_context:
{
  shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING"
}
```

ngx-paypal: "^11.0.0"