# How to remove billing address and contact information from paypal express checkout form?

Tags: javascript, express, paypal, checkout, billing

I am currently using the new paypal express checkout button to get payments online 
[paypal-button.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n85BF.png)

for more information : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/quick-start/

but the idea is that i want to make the payment so easy for guests (who don't have paypal account) with minimum typing required (only card info and their name like in stripe [stripe-payment-form.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltbvW.png)).

But paypal keeps asking for billing address and phone number [paypal-visa-checkout-form.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03XrX.png)
even if i used the

```
no_shipping: 1
```

option like mentioned here :[Remove shipping address option in PayPal Express Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40940800/remove-shipping-address-option-in-paypal-express-checkout)

and i turned the **"Contact telephone number"** in Website payment preferences to **off**.

I am currently using sandbox accounts to test my payments.

So is it possible to remove the billing address (especially that i sell digital goods only) and the contact information sections ? how ?

Do the website payment preferences take effect only in live payments ?

Do Asking for billing address and contact information affect payments rates especially from guests users ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can't control the content in the payment form, so you can't remove the fields. Credit card processors use billing details and contact information to lower their risk. Stripe allows you to just accept minimal information because they pass more of the risk onto you than PayPal does.